# add one blank line in awk on a condition

Tags: text-processing, awk

Morning everybody,

I would like to divide groups of matching lines of a file with a blank line. Being new to awk I tinkered around a bit and came up with this:

```
awk '!($0 in a) {print "\n"; a[$0]}; {print}'
```

which in my head reads as

> If the current line is not in array 'a' then print a newline and add the line to 'a'.  Print the current line.

If I run this against a testfile the output looks like

```
abc
abc


def
def
def


ghi
```

i.e. there are two blank lines printed instead of one. Where do the extra lines come from?

This is the test file I used:

```
abc
abc
def
def
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need for an associated array:

```
awk 'prev!=""{ print prev!=$0? prev ORS : $0 } { prev=$0 }
END{ if(prev!="") print prev }' infile
```

Output:

```
abc
abc

def
def
def

ghi
```

About why your `awk` is printing newline twice it's because you are using `print` statement, which by default it's printing what ever you are printing + ORS (**O**utput **R**ecord **S**eparator, which default is newline), you need to use `printf "\n"` instead or just `print ""`; and with your own solution, you could do as following (applying some fixes):

```
awk '!($0 in a) { if(c++) print "" } { a[$0]; print}' infile
```

or more compact:

```
awk '!($0 in a) && c++{ print ""} ++a[$0]' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{print ($0!=p ? s : "") $0; p=$0; s=ORS}' file
abc
abc

def
def
def

ghi
```

The mistake in your code that's leading to 2 blank lines being printed instead of 1 was using `print "\n"` instead of `print ""`, the latter being all you need to print the value of `ORS`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "---"; print "\n"; print "---"}'
---


---
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "---"; print ""; print "---"}'
---

---
```

You could alternatively have used `printf "\n"` but that's printing the hard-coded value you hope/assume that `ORS` has instead of simply printing `ORS` with `print ""`.

The main functional differences between my solution and yours are that your script would print a blank line at the start of the output while mine wouldn't (thanks to setting `s=ORS` after printing the first line) and you're saving the whole of the input file in `a[]` while I only save 1 input line, the previous one read, in `p` and so:

1. Your script would use a lot of memory and so possibly fail for huge input files while mine would work for any size input file.
2. Your script would only print a blank line if any input line had never appeared anywhere previously in the input while mine would print a blank line every time the input changed so they'd behave differently from each other if the input lines weren't always grouped together, e.g.:

```
    $ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n'
    foo
    bar
    foo

    $ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk '!($0 in a) {print ""; a[$0]}; {print}'
    
    foo
    
    bar
    foo

    $ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk '{print ($0!=p ? s : "") $0; p=$0; s=ORS}'
    foo
    
    bar
    
    foo
```

To do what you are trying to do in your code instead of an array named `a[]` we idiomatically name the array `seen[]` and update it at the same time as testing it rather than separately so your code would idiomatically have been written as `awk '!seen[$0]++{print ""} 1'` instead of `awk '!($0 in a) {print ""; a[$0]}; {print}'`:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk '!seen[$0]++{print ""} 1'

foo

bar
foo
```

and if you wanted that functionality without a leading blank line in the output, take your pick:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk '{print (seen[$0]++ ? "" : s) $0; s=ORS}'
foo

bar
foo

$ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk '!seen[$0]++ && NR>1{print ""} 1'
foo

bar
foo

$ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk '!seen[$0]++{if (NR>1) print ""} 1'
foo

bar
foo

$ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk '!seen[$0]++{printf s; s=ORS} 1'
foo

bar
foo
```

That last one would fail if ORS contained printf formatting chars, e.g.:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk -v ORS='\n%s\n' '!seen[$0]++{printf s; s=ORS} 1'
foo
%s
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=2) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `
%s
'
          ^ ran out for this one
```

so you could write it more robustly as the following if that's a concern:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | awk -v ORS='\n%s\n' '!seen[$0]++{printf "%s", s; s=ORS} 1'
foo
%s

%s
bar
%s
foo
%s
```